# Google Volley not able to get JSON values from passing parameters

Tags: json, android-volley, http-get, jsonobjectrequest

I am trying to pass a parameter which is the `userID` and then get the response in the form of the `JSON`.

So if `userID=1` then the response would be
`[{"carname":"Honda","carmodel":"Civic"}]`
and if `userID=5`then the response would be
`[{"carname":"Honda","carmodel":"Civic"},{"carname":"VW","carmodel":"Golf"},{"carname":"Ford","carmodel":"Focus"}]`

But for some reason, the parameters are not being passed and if they are then I am unable to retrieve values in `JSON`

This is my code below:

```
public void getComments(int userID){
    String passURL = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest
            (passURL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>(){

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray jsonArray) {
                    try {
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                            String carName = jsonObject.getString("carname");
                            String carModel = jsonObject.getString("carmodel");
                            UserStore userStore = new UserStore(carName, carModel);
                            list.add(userStore);
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {

                }

            }) {
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("userID", Integer.toString(userID));
            return params;
        }
    };
    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
}
```

I suspect it something to do with the fact that I am trying to get the response from the array after passing a parameter. My `php` works in `Postman`

Answer (score 0):

Using ***mcxiaoke*** library version 1.0.14 and above

**JsonArrayRequest**

You need to set the Method as Post in JsonArrayRequest as like below

```
JsonArrayRequest jsonArrReq = new JsonArrayRequest(Method.POST,
url, null,new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() 
{
......
//onResponse
......
}
```

**getParams()**

```
@Override
protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
     Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
     params.put("user", "Android");
     return params;
}
```

Comment: I am unable to have more than 3 parameters for the `new JsonArrayRequest`

Comment: @LukazsPioetrszci: you should use mcxiaoke's volley at `https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley` to have more constructors of `JsonArrayRequest`

Comment: Use @BNK mentioned Volley Library..Do you need to send any header in your request?